# Blazor Navigation not working on Firefox, why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, firefox, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My Blazor App functions correctly in most web browsers, but I'm encountering an issue specifically with Firefox. Within the application, there are external links that users can click to navigate away from my website. However, this functionality behaves as expected in all browsers except for Firefox.

When a user clicks an external link using Firefox, the browser logs a sequence of navigations, as follows:

Navigated to: https://www.google.com/
Navigated to: https://localhost:44375/

In contrast, in other browsers, the behavior is as follows:

Navigated to: https://www.google.com/

I have thoroughly investigated the possibility of a JavaScript event that might be inadvertently preventing users from leaving the page, but I couldn't identify any such event. I also attempted to address the issue by using the NavigationManager to forcibly reload the page, but the problem persisted.

Additionally, I encountered difficulty in altering the URL after the website had loaded. This functionality did not work as expected either.

Comment: Can you include all the relevant code that's being used, enough to create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @RBee there's no relevant code besides using HREF tags or the NavigationManager component

Comment: could you pls have a gif to show your symptom?

Comment: Even showing how you're using the HREF and NavigationManager is relevant code.

Comment: since some guys found it needed to delete my answer, I will add a comment, the problem you are facing is the unBeforeUnload event that is unreliable in firefox and blazor framework is using that, you can find a sample code and movie and more info on the aspnet github https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51936

Comment: @BenCroughs Yes, indeed, this was my solution... 

I had to close the connection with SignalR before loading the page because Blazor was using this to reload the page, forcing me not to go to another external page.

Thanks for your answer!
Sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to implement the redirect to google.

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>  
Welcome to your new app.

<a href="https://www.google.com/">google</a>
<div>https://www.google.com/</div>
<button onclick="@direct">direct with js invoke</button>
<button onclick="@direct2">direct with js NavigationManager</button>

@code{
    public async Task direct()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", "https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
    }

    public void direct2() {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I only get this tip(screenshot) when using `jsRuntime.InvokeAsync`.

[image]

[image]

This is my firefox version. I think you might also try to update to the latest version if it's not the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this @Tiny. The _blank tag is working, but that's not what I want. 

Ideally I want this working NavManager.NavigateTo("https://www.google.com") but it doesn't

Comment: `NavigateTo("https://www.google.com");` instead of `NavigateTo("google.com");`... I trust you know it. And could you pls have a more detailed explanation for "not working"?